# Refused connection to mLab database via MongoClient.connect() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I am trying to create a very simple website. I have created a basic database on mLab and have setup a user with dbuser = folr and dbpassword = folr. However when trying to connect I get the error message:

{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }

Why is this happening?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var db

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://folr:folr@ds047712.mlab.com:47712/familytimeline', function(err, database) {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.post('/new', function(req, res) {
  db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the mlab database through mongo shell?

Comment: @Mugali: I have. Using the following: `mongo ds047712.mlab.com:47712/familytimeline -u folr -p folr` but I get the error message: `Failed to connect to 54.166.147.240:47712, reason: errno:61 Connection refused`

Comment: It's possible the network you're on is blocking traffic to mLab. http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help

Comment: Thank you @pneumee, this was indeed the issue

Comment: @Fabian glad to hear that helped identify the issue!

Comment: how did you resolve the network problem ?@Fabian